# Printing float element of linked list displays incorrectly?

Tags: c, floating-point, linked-list

I have a linked list that reads in some information from a file and displays it to the screen. Everything reads in correctly, but when I go to display the "seconds", the number displayed is something like `-431602080.000000` instead of, for example, `27.123000`. I have no idea why.

```
 //GLOBAL VARIABLES
    struct PlayerTime* list_head = NULL;

    void besttimes_view()
    {   
        struct PlayerTime *p;
        p = list_head;

        while(p!=NULL){
            printf("%f : %s\n", p->seconds, p->name); //This prints the name correctly, but the number is wrong. Something like -431602080.000000 : Calvin
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
```

Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: Are you aware you're only setting `p->seconds` for the first element you create, which you never actually add to this list?

Comment: @rphello101, if you don't want the code on StackOverFlow go ahead and delete the question. I saw someone edited the question, didn't realize it was you, started to roll it back, then saw it was you, rolled it back to your edit. Anyway, it's your question, you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I can't delete the question because there are responses - although any moderator reading this, feel free to delete the question. I got tagged by my schools plagiarism software for posting too much code. Apparently it violated copy rights because I didn't write all of the code myself. I erased as much as I thought would leave the question comprehensible. I had to do it with a few other questions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while((fgets(input,MAX_STR_LEN,fileName)!=NULL)){
    p=(struct PlayerTime*)malloc(sizeof(struct PlayerTime));
```

You malloc a new playertime with each fgets() but you only add it to the
list every other fgets(). The one you add to the list does not have
seconds set on it, only the name.

In other words, the playertime you have set seconds on, never gets added
to the list. Only the one you have set the name on gets added to the list.

```
    if(counter==1){
        p->seconds=atof(input); // this p is never added to the list
        printf("%f\n",p->seconds); //This prints the number as it should be (e.g. 27.123000)
    }
    if(counter==2){
        strcpy(p->name,input); // this p is added to the list
        counter=0;
        p->next=list_head;
        list_head = p;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the fact that you are allocating `p` outside the `counter==1` branch. In other words, you:

1. allocate a new `p`,
2. `counter==1`, so you put time in it,
3. increase `counter`,
4. **allocate a new `p` (and discard previous one)**,
5. `counter==2`, so you put name in it and store it,
6. ...

I guess you want the `malloc()` to happen inside `if (counter==1)`.

Then, you don't reset the counter, so every next player doesn't get anything since `counter==3` and so on.